# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in on

Tags: php

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in on /* Line80 error:

```
 function write($id, $data) {
           // Get unique key
           $key = $this->getkey($id);
           // Encrypt the data
           $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);

           $time = time();
           if(!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
              $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
           }

        /* Line80 error: */  $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
           $this->w_stmt->execute();
           return true;
        }
```

Comment: Because you're not binding 'siss'

Comment: Nevermind read to fast.

Comment: So, you called `bind_param` on `$this->w_stmt` and it says it's not an object. Then you look closely and you see that you only check whether `$this->w_stmt` is set, not whether it's an instance of mysqli or whether it's an object. Therefore, check what `$this->w_stmt` is before you assume that it's an object.

Comment: can you show a table structure for this schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any error here. I think you have set variable somewhere in your class, for example as property:

```
<?php


class A
{
    private $x = '';

    public function show()
    {
        if (!isset($this->x)) {
            echo "was not set";
        }
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->show();
```

In this code no echo will be displayed, because property `$x` is set and assigned empty string.

So in your case this line:

```
$this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

is probably never executed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. `$this->w_stmt` isn't an object. You'll have to make sure that `$this->w_stmt` is an object before you attempt to call the function `bind_param`.

My guess is that `$this->w_stmt` is set (it exists), but it isn't an object.

Try something like:

```
if(!isset($this->w_stmt) || !($this->w_stmt instanceof PDOStatement)) {
    $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
}
```